# Getting changing ownership of '/var/log/logstash': Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, command-line-interface, chmod

I am running following command

```
$ chown -R logstash.logstash /usr/share/logstash
$ chmod 777 /usr/share/logstash/data
```

I'm getting below error

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/log/logstash': Operation not permitted
```

Can anyone pls help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run these commands with `sudo` for ex

```
$ sudo chown -R logstash.logstash /usr/share/logstash
$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/logstash/data
```

Read more about [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

Comment: @VatsalAgarwal glad I was helpful